# R: Piping input to a function factory

Tags: r, lazy-evaluation, magrittr

In R, I have a function that outputs a function (a function factory, as it is called).
However, when piping an input to it with `%>%`, strange errors result.

Here is a reduced example:

```
ax <- function(a) {
  function(x) a*x
}

library(magrittr)
3 %>% ax() %>% plot # Error in a * x : non-numeric argument to binary operator
ax(3) %>% plot      # works, a plot of y=3x is produced
```

[Hadley's book](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/function-factories.html#factory-fundamentals) led me to try inserting `force(a)` into the function body of `ax`. 
Now, a plot is produced in both cases.

But I am confused as to why this works. To me, the two cases are essentially identical. Why then is `force()` needed for the first case, and not the second?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of this bug: https://github.com/tidyverse/magrittr/issues/195

**Update:** Install the dev version of magrittr. Apparently this issue was already fixed, but no one had realized that. `remotes::install_github("tidyverse/magrittr")`

Nobody has touched the pipe code for two years.

They underlying issue is R Lazy evaluation. When you pass an argument to a function it is not evaluated until it is needed.

For an example of this, try this code:

```
funs <- list()
for (i in 1:3) {
  funs[[i]] <- ax(i)
}
# i is not evaluated until now. it has been modified before it is evaluated so all the calls evaluate a to the current value of i (i=3)
print(funs[[3]](1))
print(funs[[2]](1))
print(funs[[1]](1))
# lapply creates an environment for each iteration. Even though the evaluation is delayed, it maps to the expected value of a
funs2 <- lapply(1:3, ax)
print(funs2[[3]](1))
print(funs2[[2]](1))
print(funs2[[1]](1))
```

If you add `force(a)` you force the evaluation of `a` when `ax` is called, not when funs[[i]] is called, getting the expected behaviour.

If I had traced exactly why the bug happens I would probably have submitted a pull request to magrittr already. Maybe it's worth spending some time debugging that... Or maybe someone will soon implement an rlang-based pipe, with a smaller and easier to follow implementation, that fixes most of magrittr shortcomings. (See the issues in the magrittr repository for more details)

Comment: The examples to illustrate `force` and lazy evaluation helped. Thanks! :) Looking around the issues in the magrittr repo, I have a hunch that magrittr may have messed with the function's environment, causing the bug..

Comment: Apparently the magrittr author simplified the implementation of a function 5 years ago and fixed this issue in the process, although he did not know the issue existed. I guess it's time for a new magrittr release! :-)